# What does that mean? #define SOMENAME ((uint32_t *)0x130010f0

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand some sample C code that I got with my microcontroller board. I have a really hard time to understand that whole pointer thing. I read a lot of posts in this forum and I also read several tutorials and slowly I get the hang of it :) But...
In my sample code there is the following line of code, which I could not decrypt with any information that I have found yet.

```
#define SOMENAME ((uint32_t *)0x130010f0)
```

I understood, that `#define` simply replaces all occurrences of SOMENAME in the compiled code with the respective statement (don't know if this is correctly explained, but I really think I got what this is doing).

Now, what I could imagine, what the rest of the statement means is the following:

SOMENAME is now a pointer to the address 0x130010f0 but without being an actual variable.

Is this correct? And I could kind of use it for example as: `printf("value at address 0x130010f0: %p",SOMENAME)` because the compiler would replace it with `printf("value at address 0x130010f0: %p",((uint32_t *)0x130010f0))` and this gives the value stored at that address? What would be the print statement if I want the address of that pointer? I can't, right? Because the pointer does not have an address as it is not a variable? Very confusing...

The example is quite complex and this definition is also part of other definitions which are pointers to structs of structs of structs, therefore this "simple" example. Below you can find the "whole" structure:

```
#define ROM_API_TREE ((uint32_t *)0x130010f0)
#define BOOTLOADER_POINTER ((bootloader_tree_t *)ROM_API_TREE)

flash_driver_interface_t *FLASH_API_TREE
#define FLASH_API_TREE BOOTLOADER_POINTER->flashDriver

typedef struct BootloaderTree{
 ...
 const flash_driver_interface_t *flashDriver;
} bootloader_tree_t

typedef struct FlashDriverInterface{
 ...
 status_t (*ffr_get_uuid)(flash_config_t *config, uint8_t *uuid);
} flash_driver_interface_t

/*
* I actually want to understand that statement, but as I fail 
* already at the beginning, I posted this question
*/
status_t = FLASH_API_TREE->ffr_get_uuid(config,uuid);
```

Comment: I'd recommend to study [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/questions/276290). Because you got various potential bugs/hazards in this code.

Comment: Hi Lundin, this is not my own code but a sample code that was delivered with the MCU. I just try to understand it :) But thanks anyway, I'll have a look right away.

Comment: All the more reason to worry then. MCU vendors are notoriously bad at writing firmware. I think there's some on-going competition about which MCU vendor that has the worst programmers in the world. Lots of prestige involved. This is from NXP, yeah? They are one of the market leaders in broken firmware, but the competition is fierce.

Comment: How did you know it's from NXP? Impressive :) Thanks for the hint, but as I am still only a student and not very good at coding, I will leave it like this at the moment and maybe when I am more skilled I can actually make it better :) But good to know that such code is sometimes not really good...

Comment: Because I mostly work with NXP parts and I think I have read this very code before... flash driver/bootloader for some LPC flavour Cortex M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `SOMENAME` get replaced by the preprocessor with `((uint32_t *)0x130010f0)`.  What this gives you is a pointer to a `uint32_t`, and the value of that pointer is `0x130010f0`.

When you then do this:

```
printf("value at address 0x130010f0: %p",SOMENAME);
```

You'll actually print the *value* of the pointer, i.e. 0x130010f0, not what it points to.  For that you would need to dereference it, i.e.:

```
printf("value at address 0x130010f0: %u", *SOMENAME);
```

This however assumes that 0x130010f0 is a valid address that can be dereferenced and read.  This will typically only be the case in some particular embedded environment where the implementation allows it.

Comment: Because the example is from "C code that I got with my microcontroller board" chances are there is something to read there (namely function pointers).

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense! So the first print statement (SOMENAME) gives the value of the pointer and the second (*SOMENAME) gives the value at the address the pointer points to?! Thanks a lot, this helped!

Answer (score 1):

As i saw, you basically could understand many things behind the Pointers. The SOMENAME is a `macro` not a variable right. Before i get to the code, a pointer in general is nothing else but a variable that contains an adress instead of having a value.
`printf("value at address 0x130010f0: %p",SOMENAME);` is wrong because the `%p` expects a value not an Adress and you are passing the adress to it, so you all you have to do is to dereference it using the `*`.
When you write `(uint32_t *)0x130010f0` you are casting the adress to the type writteb between parentheses.

Whenever it gets complicated while using pointers try to remember this small example:

```
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;// declare pointer of type integer. This is valid, adress of an integer variable contains adress of integer variable
int *j; //declare pointer of type integer
j = &a; //correct, because j expects an adress.
*j = &a; //wrong *j expects a value
 
printf("value of p: %p", *p);
printf("adress of p: %p", p); //or &p
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually have such a small example in front of me, but I did not get it correctly... Well, I think I understood it now.

Comment: @straumle if not, feel free to ask. If you think the Answer helped, dont forget to vote.

Answer (score 0):

This shows that your microcontroller board has a program accessible 32-bit device.

I say 'accessible' because this device could be readable, writable or both.

I use the kinda general term 'device' because it could be all kinds of things. Quite often it's a register that simply stores a value, but it could also be a FIFO chip returning the next stored value at every read.

Assuming it's a register: These registers often consist of separate bits or small groups of bits to represent some function. In that case you'd see bitfield `struct` declarations that look like this (two 16-bit fields as example):

```
struct {
    uint32_t someField : 16;
    uint32_t otherField : 16;
} fields;
```

Comment: I think the specific code comes from a NXP flash driver to some LPC Cortex M. I have this eerie feeling that I've seen this very code before, when I wrote a bootloader for such a part.